# Collision Detection Issue in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

I have got a game where the user can move a player (“mrhinckleberg”) using arrow keys. There are also two "enemies" which bounce automatically up and down.

How can I now detect a collision between the player and an enemy?

Here is my code I have so far:

```
import pygame
import time
pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((800,800))
pygame.display.set_caption("Yues")
theboard = pygame.image.load('theboard.png')
enemy = pygame.image.load('mrenemy.png')
mrhinckleberg = pygame.image.load('MrHinckleBerg.png')
mrhincklebergdead = pygame.image.load('MrHinckleBergdead.png')
deathscreen = pygame.image.load('deathscreen.png')
black = (0,0,0)
clock1 = pygame.time.Clock()
def quitt():
    pygame.quit()
    quit()
playerx = 750
playery = 450
enemydirection = 'down'
enemyx = 500
enemyy = 50
enemyspeed = 100
enemydirection2 = 'up'
enemyx2 = 350
enemyy2 = 750
enemyspeed2 = 50
enemydirection3 = 'down'
enemyx3 = 200
enemyy3 = 50
enemyspeed3 = 150


while True:
    window.blit(theboard, (0,0))
    if enemydirection == 'down':
        enemyy += enemyspeed
        if enemyy >= 790:
            enemydirection = 'up'
    elif enemydirection == 'up':
        enemyy -= enemyspeed
        if enemyy <= 10:
            enemydirection = 'down'


    if enemydirection2 == 'up':
        enemyy2 -= enemyspeed2
        if enemyy2 <= 10:
            enemydirection2 = 'down'
    elif enemydirection2 == 'down':
        enemyy2 += enemyspeed2
        if enemyy2 >= 790:
            enemydirection2 = 'up'

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            quitt()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerx += 12
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerx -= 12
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                playery -= 12
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                playery += 12
    if playerx == enemyx and playery == enemyy:
           print("hai")
    window.blit(theboard, (0,0))
    window.blit(mrhinckleberg, (playerx,playery))
    window.blit(enemy, (enemyx,enemyy))
    window.blit(enemy, (enemyx2,enemyy2))
    window.blit(enemy, (enemyx3,enemyy3))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: This code really needs to be more organized. And you should use rectangles rather than a bunch of single variables. And your movement will be very choppy. And you haven't indicated the problem. The list goes on and on.

Comment: I can't figure out how to make it so when the two images have the same x and y it does something. I know its not organized well and stuff but im new to pygame. @MalikBrahimi

Comment: Use Pygame rectangles, they have built-in methods for collision and overlap.

Comment: But I want pictures not boring rectangles

Comment: You don't understand. Rectangles manage the position of the image, we're not drawing rectangles. It's a class to help us for collision management and drawing. Please provide a link to your full project including images so that I may work on it.

Comment: Could I email you it?

Comment: Yes at mbrahimi02@gmail.com

Comment: @SilverFire: I added the new code (with images) in my first answer!

Answer (score 0):

In my opionion the problem is that you check for instance if variable `playerx` **is equal** to `enemyx`, but this will never be true since you change the `enemyx` variable only in specfic intervals (add or subtract 12).

To avoid this you could check if `playerx` / `playery` and `enemyx` / `enemyy` are in ** a certain range**:

```
if (playerx <= enemyx <= playerx + playerWidth) and \
   (playery <= enemyy <= playery + playerHeight):
       print("hai")
```

Note that in Python comparisons can be chained. This means that `5 < x <= 10` is equivalent to `5 < x and x <= 10`. For more information see [Built-in Types -> Comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons).

---

Updated code:

```
import pygame
import time
pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((800,800))
pygame.display.set_caption("Yues")

theboard = pygame.image.load('theboard.png')

enemy = pygame.image.load('mrenemy.png')

mrhinckleberg = pygame.image.load('MrHinckleBerg.png')
mrhincklebergdead = pygame.image.load('MrHinckleBergdead.png')

deathscreen = pygame.image.load('deathscreen.png')

playerWidth = mrhinckleberg.get_rect().width
playerHeight = mrhinckleberg.get_rect().height

black = (0,0,0)

clock1 = pygame.time.Clock()
def quitt():
    pygame.quit()
    quit()

playerx = 750
playery = 450

enemydirection = 'down'
enemyx = 500
enemyy = 50
enemyspeed = 3

enemydirection2 = 'up'
enemyx2 = 350
enemyy2 = 750
enemyspeed2 = 2

enemydirection3 = 'down'
enemyx3 = 200
enemyy3 = 50
enemyspeed3 = 1


while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            quitt()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerx += 12
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerx -= 12
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                playery -= 12
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                playery += 12

    if enemydirection == 'down':
        enemyy += enemyspeed
        if enemyy >= 790:
            enemydirection = 'up'
    elif enemydirection == 'up':
        enemyy -= enemyspeed
        if enemyy <= 10:
            enemydirection = 'down'

    if enemydirection2 == 'up':
        enemyy2 -= enemyspeed2
        if enemyy2 <= 10:
            enemydirection2 = 'down'
    elif enemydirection2 == 'down':
        enemyy2 += enemyspeed2
        if enemyy2 >= 790:
            enemydirection2 = 'up'

    if (playerx <= enemyx <= playerx + playerWidth) and (playery <= enemyy <= playery + playerHeight):
       print("hai")

    window.blit(theboard, (0,0))

    window.blit(mrhinckleberg, (playerx,playery))

    window.blit(enemy, (enemyx,enemyy))
    window.blit(enemy, (enemyx2,enemyy2))
    window.blit(enemy, (enemyx3,enemyy3))

    pygame.display.update()
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Where would I get the playerWidth and PlayerHeight from?

Comment: @SilverFire: `mrhinckleberg.get_rect().width` or `mrhinckleberg.get_rect().height` :)

Comment: Where would I place tht, and does that return a width that goes into the place of playerWidth? Im confused

Comment: @SilverFire: place this after your `image.load()` function: `playerWidth = mrhinckleberg.get_rect().width`. `playerWidth` is a variable.

Comment: Should I do the same for Height?

Comment: I did all that yet it still doesnt print hai when they overlap each other.

Comment: @SilverFire: In my opinion it works perfect! Try to change the speed of your enemies to `1` or `2` so you can see them.

Comment: Can you show me the code that you used? Like all of it to make it work :)